# Show that $(1, e^{it},e^{2it},..,e^{(n-1)it})$ has at most $n-1$ roots on $[0,2 \pi]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I need to show that $(1, e^{it},e^{2it},...,e^{(n-1)it})$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-Cebyshev system, to do that I can prove one of the following statements:

1. For each ${z_1, ..., z_n} \subseteq [0, 2 \pi]$ the determinant of the Vandermode matrix is not equal to 0
2. Each non-trivial linear combination of $(1, e^{it},e^{2it},..,e^{(n-1)it})$ has at most $n-1$ roots in $[0, 2 \pi]$
3. For each $Z = {z_1, ..., z_n} \subseteq [0, 2 \pi]$ the functions $(1|_Z, e^{it}|_Z,e^{2it}|_Z,...,e^{(n-1)it}|_Z)$ are linearly independent.

I'm not sure whether using the fundamental theorem of algebra would suffice to prove the second condition. Could you write $(1, e^{it},e^{2it},...,e^{(n-1)it})$ as a polynomial of degree $n-1$: $((e^{it})^0, ((e^{it})^1, ..., ((e^{it})^{n-1})$, which would have $n-1$ roots on $[0, 2 \pi]$ according to the theorem. Would that be enough to validate the second condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the map $\exp_1:\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$ given by $\exp_1(t)=\exp(2\pi\mathbf it)$, your functions are just defined by composing $\exp_1$ with evaluation of the monomials $1,X,X^2,\ldots,X^{n-1}$, respectively. This is compatible with linear combinations, so forming a linear combination of those functions is just composing $\exp_1$ with evaluation of a polynomial of degree${}<n$. Condition 2 is then saying that such a polynomial, if nonzero, can have at most $n-1$ roots on the image of $\exp_1$, i.e., on the unit circle; this is obvious since such a polynomials has at most $n-1$ roots in all of$~\Bbb C$.